# How to get specific part of a string in node.js?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string, data-manipulation

I'm trying to do something fun with twitter API,
I want to search on twitter with #np (now playing) tag and split tweet by song name and artist name.

lets assume that it found this tweet

*"Listen to It Will Happen by L.E.L #np on #SoundCloud"*

I want to take song name, song artist and bind to variables.

and tweet can be something like this too

*"just awesome :D #np Zombie (metal cover by Leo & Stine Moracchioli) https://youtu.be/4e4bAsQ4r30  via @YouTube"*

I'm getting trouble with understanding regex so can somebody show me a proper way to do this 2 example?

Comment: Unless there's a clear format at work, it will be very difficult to parse this out. Especially if there is other regular text in with the same tweet. So if "Listen(ing) to" is just text, you want to ignore it. If "It Will Happen" is the track title, you want to grab it. But how would you tell the difference between a track name and any other text? This is just an example, but that should give you an idea of how difficult it could be.

Comment: If you have some control over what such a tweet "looks like," then we could figure out ways of parsing things out of it. For example, `{track title} by {artist} #np` would be easier to figure out, because the parts have been marked with those curly brackets. Hard to give more specific help without a more definite structure, though. Sorry.

Comment: If you have more specific questions about regex and what it's capable of, I'd be happy to help all the same.

Comment: yes It's hard to find a pattern in random user input unless you search by detailed options and exclude rest of them, most of people share directly within soundcloud or youtube without comment, so that means most of them has a common way, twitter gives us the ability of detailed search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's hardly a pattern to find in random user input.
However, if most of it code generated by some source then there's often still find a pattern to be matched.

It probably needs to be separated by the source.
Since it makes it easier to deal with the capture groups.

```js
var tweetString = "Listen to It Will Happen by L.E.L #np on #SoundCloud";
var myRegexp = /^(.*)(?: by (.*))#\w+.* on #(\w+)$/;
var song = "";
var artists = "";
var messagesource = "";
match = myRegexp.exec(tweetString);
if (match != null) {
  song = match[1];
  artist = match[2];
  messagesource = match[3];
  console.log("song: " + song);
  console.log("artist: " + artist);
  console.log("messagesource: " + messagesource);
}
```

```js
var tweetString = "just awesome :D #np Zombie (metal cover by Leo & Stine Moracchioli) https://youtu.be/4e4bAsQ4r30 via @YouTube";
var myRegexp = /^.*#\w+ (.*?)\(.* by (.*)\).* via @(\w+)$/;
var song = "";
var artists = "";
var messagesource = "";
match = myRegexp.exec(tweetString);
if (match != null) {
  song = match[1];
  artist = match[2];
  messagesource = match[3];
  console.log("song: " + song);
  console.log("artist: " + artist);
  console.log("messagesource: " + messagesource);
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot, yes It's hard to find a pattern in random user input unless you search by detailed options and exclude rest of them, its the answer, by the way I'm still having trouble with understanding regex can you give me a detailed source for working on it? :)

Comment: [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is often recommended.  And to experiment with the regex flavor used in javascript I recommend [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), which also has a good reference, with examples. And to experiment with the PCRE flavor [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is often used here on stackoverflow to show examples.

Answer (score 2):

An explanation for @LukStorms:

- `^` start of string
- `.*` the `.` matches any character except new lines (`\n`). The `*` means the previous part should be there 0 more more times
- `#` literal `#` character
- `\w+` the `\w` matches any letter, uppercase or lower case (or underscores, but that usually doesn't matter); `+` means the previous part (`\w`) should be there 1 or more times
- `(.*?)` the brackets wrap around a capturing group (which you can actually access). In this case, the group would match
- `\(` a literal `(` character. The `\` "escapes" the next character, turning it special, or making it unspecial ;P
- `.*` 0 or more non-newline characters
- `by` literal text
- `(.*)` a capturing group containing 0 or more non-newline characters
- `\)` literal `)`
- `.*` 0 or more non-newline characters
- `via @` literal text
- `(\w+)` a capturing group containing one or more letters
- `$` end of string

Hope this helps. If you're trying to figure this kind of stuff out, or the flow of logic in a regex, you could use regex101, as @LukStorms said. Or something I use is [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%5E.*%23%5Cw%2B%20(.*%3F)%5C(.*%20by%20(.*)%5C).*%20via%20%40(%5Cw%2B)%24).